# PHP/MYSQL - How do i assign data fetched from the database(stored in variables) to a session variable?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am having a bit of an issue passing array variables that are fetched from the database and stored in variables and passing them into session variables to use all over the site.

Code:

```
$rid=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] ;

$recquery = 'SELECT * FROM clinic_receptionist,clinic_table where clinic_receptionist.recep_clinic_id = clinic_table.ID AND recep_id ='.$rid;

$recresult = mysqli_query($conn,$recquery);

if(mysqli_num_rows($recresult)>0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recresult))
{
$cid = $row['clinic_id'];
$cname = $row['clinic_name'];
$name = $row['recep_full_name'];
$phone = $row['recep_mobile'];
$email = $row['recep_email'];
$address = $row['recep_address'];
$gender = explode(",",$row['recep_gender']);
$dob = $row['recep_dob'];
$doj = $row['recep_doj'];
}
}
?>
```

The above code is where the select query is happening. I wanted to know how do I assign `$cid` and `$cname` to a `$_SESSION` variable in different pages. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

CODE:

```
<?php session_start();
include('header.php');

include('menu.php');
include('config.php');

$appquery = 'SELECT * FROM appointment_table,clinic_table where clinic_table.ID = appointment_table.clinic_id';
$appresult = mysqli_query($conn,$appquery);
if(mysqli_num_rows($appresult)>0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($appresult))
{
$_SESSION['cid'] = $row['ID'];
$_SESSION['cname'] = $row['clinic_name'];
$ptdate = $row['date'];
$pttime = $row['time'];
$ptname = $row['pt_name'];
$ptphone = $row['pt_ph_num'];
$ptemail = $row['pt_email_id'];

}
}
?>
```

The above code is the place from where I want to receive the id and clinic name.

Comment: `$_SESSION['id'] = $cid` and `$_SESSION['name'] = $cname`

Comment: Is there any specific reason to open & close so many php tags instead of just one? Wouldn't that be neater?

Comment: @bIgBoY Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();

    //Assigning the values to $_SESSION
    $_SESSION['cid'] = $row['clinic_id'];

    $_SESSION['cname'] = $row['clinic_name'];;
    ?>
```

[session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Sorry sessions usually confuse me, how do I get the same `$cid` that will match with `$rid`

Comment: did u mean by `$rid` corresponding `$cid`? Since you have given condition in your select query it will result only corresponding `$cid`.

Comment: no `$cid` corresponds to a clinic id and `$rid` corresponds to a receptionist id that works in the particular clinic.

Comment: I think you should mention the `$cid` in receptionist table and join with the clinic table.ie each receptionist should have corresponding clinic id right?if so i suppose should do so.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `session_start()` on each page to initialize the session, of course; after that you can just

```
$_SESSION['cid'] = $cid;
$_SESSION['cname'] = $cname;
```

to store those values in `$_SESSION`.

By the way, someone's going to tell you to use a prepared statement for that query, so it might as well be me.

Perhaps an illustration is in order.

**page1.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();  // find session, or create new one

    include('header.php');
    include('menu.php');
    include('config.php');

    $appquery = 'SELECT * FROM appointment_table,clinic_table where clinic_table.ID = appointment_table.clinic_id';

    $appresult = $conn->query($appquery);
    if(($rowcount = $appresult->num_rows()) > 0)
    {
        // create arrays to pass data
        $cids = array($rowcount);
        $cnames = array($rowcount);
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $appresult->fetch_array())
        {
            // add values to arrays
            $cids[$i] = $row['ID'];
            $cnames[$i] = $row['clinic_name'];
            $i++;
        }
        // add arrays to session
        $_SESSION['cids'] = $cids;
        $_SESSION['cnames'] = $cnames;
    }
```

**page2.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();  // find session, or create new one

    include('header.php');
    include('menu.php');
    include('config.php');

    // retrieve arrays from session        
    $cnames = $_SESSION['cnames'];
    $cids = $_SESSION['cids'];

    // ... and print them
    $count = count($cids);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        echo "cid = " . $cid[$i] . "; cname = " . $cname[$i] . "<br>";
    }
```

**page1.php** performs the query and stores `cid` and `cname` values in arrays which are then stored in `$_SESSION`. **page2.php** retrieves the arrays from `$_SESSION` and echoes them out. In production, of course, it would be considered more efficient to run the query on the page where it is displayed, and only pass key values between pages.

I've also used object syntax instead of procedural syntax for `mysqli`, just to show what it looks like. As usual, I leave error handling as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thanks for the reply but will it know from where the session is getting declared?

Comment: If there isn't already a session open, php sets a `session_id` cookie in the browser. The next call to `session_start()` looks for that cookie in order to resume the session.

Comment: `session_start()` does all the heavy lifting for you; all you need to do is call it at the top of each page.

Comment: I have added it in the files but when I echo the variables `$clinic_name = $_SESSION['cname']` and `$clinic_id = $_SESSION['cid']` it just says `Array`

Comment: Hi, Darwin I have editted the code, and added the code where the cid and cname should be displayed. If you could please have a look.

Comment: I don't see you assigning any values *to* `$_SESSION`. `$_SESSION` works just like an ordinary array - you have to put values in before you can get them out.

Comment: Hi Darwin, I have edited the code again, this is what I added currently it shows the same value for all the users that I login with

Comment: Well, yes. `$_SESSION` is an array, but `$_SESSION['cid']` et. al. are simple scalars. You keep overwriting them in your loop, so you only end up passing the last value. If you want to pass a *list* of `cid` values, then you'll have to put them into an array and assignt the *array* to `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Sorry but could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Hey Darwin thanks for the answer and update, but I got it working by using the `$rid`. Thank you guys for all the help :)